# How to run moment.js in pug templates?

Tags: node.js, pug, momentjs

I have a control which will render a pug template with an array of objects.

```
res.render('template.pug', {objects: objects});
```

In the template, I'll loop through the array and modify the date to `local date/time.` I'd like to call the moment function to implement this.

Is it possible to call the moment function in the pug template? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Why are you not willing to loop in the controller?  That would be the most efficient place to do this conversion.

Comment: Something else - when you run moment on the server you will be getting the local time for the server and not the client.  You either need to pass the timezone offset in from the client or send the data to the client to process it there.

Answer (score 7):

You can import/pass the `moment.js` library in your existing `objects` array like this,

```
var objects= {
  someExitingKey1: 'Some value 1',
  someExitingKey2: 'Some value 2',
  ........,
  ........,
  ........,
  moment: require('moment')
};
```

And in your `template.pug` you can make use of the moment library functions like,

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    span= moment(someDateValue).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply. The objects are retrieved from MongoDB database. How could I efficiently embed the "moment: require('moment')" into each object? I am not willing to  loop in the controller. Any suggestion?

Comment: no, not in every object. you should pass `moment` like this `res.render('template.pug', {objects: objects, moment: require('moment')}); ` or better import `moment` into your pug/html file using CDN and then simpy use `moment`

Comment: @zerosand1s Yes, That would the apt way to do that.

Comment: Thank you, David and Zerosand1s. I decide to use app.locals.moment that Graham provides since I don't change much in the controllers.

Answer (score 7):

In your app.js (or server.js or whatever launches your node app) add the following line:

```
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

This will make moment available in all of your pug templates as `moment`.  Of course, also make sure that you have run `npm install moment --save` to add it to your package.json and download the package.

Comment: Thank you, Graham. It's quite simple and easy.